# What could I be doing incorrectly in this loop

Tags: c, loops, nested-loops

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void print_alphabet(void)
{
    char a[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    int i = 0;
    int n;
    for (n = 0; n <= 9; n++)
    {
        while (a[i] != '\0')
        {
            putchar(a[i]);
            i++;
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
    return;
}

int main(void)
{
    print_alphabet();
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to print the alphabet 10 times with each series on a different line but, when I compile and execute my code, I only get one line of the complete alphabet and 9 blank new line.

Comment: You should indent your code properly. Curly braces all placed in the first column makes this unreadable.

Comment: Hint: what is the value of `i` at the start of the second iteration of the `for` loop?

Comment: @TomKarzes `i` doesn't get iterated past the position of the trailing '\0'.  This is well defined behavior.

Comment: @AllanWind Oops, right, it just gets stuck at the null character.

Comment: Have you tried running your code line-by-line in a debugger while monitoring the values of all variables, in order to determine in which line your program stops behaving as intended? If you did not try this, then you may want to read this: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/12149471) If you run your code line-by-line while monitoring the value of `i`, then the error in your code should become obvious.

Comment: @ThomasJager sorry about the readability, i'm currently learning how to code. The programme i'm enrolled in, requires code to be written in that specific style.

Comment: @SomteeTunechiOnu I would be skeptical about any place that teaches you to code like that. That's horrific style and would be unacceptable in any project you'd work on. You can't tell what's nested where, it's a jumble of equally indented statements, with random curly braces at the beginning (as if they're considered unimportant).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't set `i` inside the `for` loop, so the condition of the `while` loop `a[i] != '\0'` remains false for `n > 1`.  This means the body of the `while` loop doesn't get executed again.  Use another `for` loop instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_alphabet(void) {
    const char a[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    for (unsigned char n = 0; n < 10; n++) {
        for(unsigned char i = 0; a[i]; i++) {
            putchar(a[i]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
    return;
}

int main(void) {
    print_alphabet();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for (unsigned char n = 0; n < 10; n++) {` is  a premature optimization.  Better as `unsigned`, `int` or perhaps `uint_fast8_t`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica how is using an appropriate type (unsigned and small matching range of use) premature optimization?

Comment: No reason for small matching range as it readily makes for slower, more code and adds maintenance issues.  If that does not satisfy, consider posting a question about it.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is correct but if you want to use your original approach with the `while` loop, you just need to add the statement `i=0;` inside the `for` loop, just before the `while` statement.